# Set a relative search path for fontspec within a package (.sty file)

Tags: xetex, fontspec, kpathsea

I have a small `.sty` file for beamer, where I need to specify a particular title font (that's a TTF file). I can do this thus:

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\WellcomeBold}[Path=fonts/]{wellcome-bold.ttf}
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\WellcomeBold}
```

If the `.sty` is in my current directory, then all is good, the font `fonts/wellcome-bold.ttf` is loaded, and away we go. If, though, I install the package in a standard location (e.g. ~/texmf/tex/latex/foo`) and put the ttf in a fonts/ subdirectory, then I get a fontspec file not found error.

So: how can I tell fontspec to look for a path *relative to the .sty file location* rather than relative to CWD?

Now, obviously, I could separately install the .ttf file where fontspec will find it, but I want to be able to provide the .sty and font (and some graphics, but those work in the obvious manner) together, so the font needs to be a subdirectory of the package dir.

Comment: In TeX usually ALL relatives belonga .tex that is why and when the .sty is in the same directory as the .tex its relatives behaves good and neighbourly. Otherwise it is down to system TDS defaults as determined  primarily by kpathsea relative rules 1) Personal .sty package should NOT be in master texmf 2) Fonts SHOULD be in master texmf thus there would not be a good relative link to package. 3) Fonts can be in folder relative to working.tex without problems but that is not ideal as most users would need ../../fonts/ or similar